# Check string is not blank - Zapier Javascript - Return alternate value

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'm using Zapier to process a Webhook response and need to check if the first input name is blank, then return the second one.

Think name and nickname. If the user inputs their nickname in `NAME1`, then use that name, otherwise return their actual name in `NAME2`.

This is the JavaScript code that I have added as a step in Zapier, however when using the `name` variable in a required field in another step doesn't work.

```
var output = 'No Name';
if(inputData.NAME1 != '') {
  output ={name: inputData.NAME1};
} else {
  output= {name: inputDate.NAME2};
}
return output;
```

Screenshot of [Input code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhqEH.png) accessed via Task History

Screenshot of [Output code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cct2x.png) accessed via Task Hostory

I have tried both assigning `output` and returning it at the end, or returning it in the if statement.

In the Zapier test step it looks like it is working fine, it's just when it runs then it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

The issue is with your comparison. When NAME1 isn't passed in, it's `undefined`.

In JS, `undefined` doesn't equal '', so the first branch always gets run. Unfortunately, `NAME1` is undefined, so it's not shown in the output.

You could simplify the code to the following:

`return {name: inputData.NAME2 || inputData.NAME1 || 'No Name'}`

which will pick the names in the order you want, plus has a default.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Great, thanks - I haven't seen this format used before, it's working fine.